# Micrometer - how to create timers with tags relating to outcome/response

Tags: micrometer

I'd like to create some Micrometer Timer based metrics which include tags with values based on the outcome or response of the timed task - eg like outcome and  HTTP status on RestTemplate calls with in Spring Boot.

However, as the tags are defined when creating the metric, before the task to be timed is run, I don't understand how to achieve this.

I've tried digging through the Spring Framework/Spring Boot code to see how they've achieved it, but whilst I can identify they are using the Observation API and how they are getting the tag values from a Context I cannot work out how/where they are creating the metric itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works out of the box, you don't need to add it.
See classes in [`org.springframework.http.client.observation`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/2685a35c3a3016f6197e2a5586f804cdc7f2047d/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/observation).

[`ClientRequestObservationContext`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2685a35c3a3016f6197e2a5586f804cdc7f2047d/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/observation/ClientRequestObservationContext.java) holds the data about your call (request, response, etc.) while [`DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2685a35c3a3016f6197e2a5586f804cdc7f2047d/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/observation/DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention.java) sets the key-values (tags). YOu can provide your own implementation of [`ClientRequestObservationConvention`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2685a35c3a3016f6197e2a5586f804cdc7f2047d/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/observation/ClientRequestObservationConvention.java) if you want to customize this behavior. Or you can use an `ObservationFilter` to customize `Observation`s too.